# Failed to convert parameter value from a Int32 to a DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server

I searched all webs and didn't find any solution for my problem. I am new to c# and stack overflow community but am really stuck in this issue.

I have a button to add date and time separately into a `datagridview`. While filling the rows  i am saving row values in SQL Server  but its giving exception   `Failed to convert parameter value from a Int32 to a DateTime` when i send it database.data type in c# and SQL Server  is `Datetime`

**Here's the code of adding date and time to datagridview**

```
private void addDateTime2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value =  dateTimePicker9.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dateTimePicker7.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); 
}
```

**Here's the code that i insert to database:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
    string StrQuery = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[callRedirect]  (ISFsectionId, callRedirectDate, incidentNo, callRedirectTime, callRedirectGrade, callRedirectFName, callRedirectLName, callRedirectSerialNo, callRedirectRemark) VALUES (@ISFsectionId, @callRedirectDate, @incidentNo, @callRedirectTime, '" 
+ dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column12"].Tag + "', '" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column13"].Value + "', '" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column14"].Value + "', '" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column20"].Value + "', '" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column19"].Value + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = StrQuery;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@incidentNo", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callRedirectDate",  dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callRedirectTime", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ISFsectionId", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column11"].Tag;
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: In the debugger, what is the value of dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value?

Comment: Have you tried .. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callRedirectDate",  Convert.ToDatetime(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));

Comment: The error says that the datatype is *not* DateTime but `int`. Your code stores *strings* instead of dates in the grid, but that is another (serious) bug. The only line that can throw this error is `    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ISFsectionId", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column11"].Tag;` And I'd bet that `Tag` contains an int

Comment: It looks like you're building your own query here. While that's completly fine (as long you're protected for SQL injection) you need to write correct data into your database. The `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` however changed the format of your datetime. It then gets stored as a string and when you make the query it probably breaks because of the bad format. Please look how you should format a datetime in a query and compare it with your query.

Comment: its custom format dd-MM-yyyy and its inserted to datagridview like 26-05-2016

Comment: so true the ISFsection should be int in datatype i correected it then it give me 
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only line that could throw this error is

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ISFsectionId", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column11"].Tag;
```

I seriously doubt that your `ISFsectionId` is a `datetime`. I'm also going to bet that `Tag` contains an integer.

Also note that your grid contains string values instead of DateTimes. This means that either you use string fields of actual `date` and `time`, or that ADO.NET is accidentally able to parse your strings to the underlying type. I say accidentally, because this could break if the code run on a locale with different formatting.

To avoid conversion issues, use `date` and `time` types in the database and *don't* convert them to string when loading them and binding them to the grid. Use the [DataGridViewStyle.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx) property of each column to specify how you want it to be displayed

Comment: so true Panagiotis Kanavos it should be Int .sorry my mistake. thanks a lot everyone